# subgridRowColapsed event never fired

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Im using free-jqgrid and trying to simply hande subgrid collapsed event (**subGridRowColapsed**). However it's never get triggered. 
I've tried **jqGridSubgridRowColapsed** also and same result.
subGridRowExpanded works fine.

```js
...
subGridRowColapsed: function (pID, rID) {
          console.log("YES");
},
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good if you post the version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which you use.

In any way, free jqGrid don't support neither `subGridRowColapsed` callback nor the event `jqGridSubgridRowColapsed`. There are exist callbacks `subGridBeforeCollapse`, `subGridBeforeExpand`, `subGridRowExpanded` and events `jqGridSubGridBeforeCollapse`, `jqGridSubGridBeforeExpand`, `jqGridSubGridRowExpanded`, which can be used. See [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.5/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L2117-L2120) and [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.5/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L1166-L1173) as short documentation.